# Would topics of biophysics and medical physics be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

As well as Environmental physics.

Would these topics be considered on topic here - specifically, I am looking at instrumentation for monitoring and evaluation, as well as, for example - a comparison of UVA and UVB energy on the human skin and eyes.

Comment: Why not? But, anybody using the word "receptor" should be banned with extreme prejudice. :]

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, it depends on the question. However, note that [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com), [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), and [the Sustainable Living SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com) exist too. Look at their respective help centers ("help" link up top, see the "What topics can I ask about here?" sections) and try to determine which site your question belongs on. If you end up asking on the wrong site, don't worry, it can be migrated (or improved to fit that site better).

I suggest you ask the question first and link to it in this post. Usually one deals with choosing the right site for interdisciplinary questions on a per-case basis. Note that some questions can be on topic for more than one site; in which case you can ask on either.

---

In this case, it looks like your question would be better on Biology.SE. It could be on topic here; but I doubt that you would get an answer.

Comment: good advice! I will get my question on here very soon.  It is fun to have a multidisciplinary research focus (medical and atmospheric physics being mine).

Comment: @DamienIgoe: Colin McFaul is [a Physics student, doing research in chemistry, which finally has applications in biology.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5211163#5211163), even more interdisciplinary! :D

Comment: (I myself am currently working with graphene -- lots of chemistry involved, but lots more physics. Yay!)

Comment: Now, that is a lot of interdisciplinarisms! (new word!).  The optical properties of graphene intrigue me immensely.

Comment: @DamienIgoe: There's a chance I may be working on just that. I'm currently learning the prerequisites though :)

Comment: I am also at the ground level with understanding graphene (currently, silicon is my main vessel of optical-research), but what I am reading is exciting - very exciting, particularly UV based applications.

Comment: The question is posted here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68012/what-is-the-relationship-between-uv-wavelength-and-penetration-depth-into-human